# Config file being overwritten in WCF service

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

All right. Normally i'de hate to ask questions but this problem im having has been clawing my brains out.

The company is developing a wcf service that communicates with sharepoint. we managed to get it to work and it receives calls and files from sharepoint however it only works for small files. the settings in sharepoint are set to accept files up to 250 MB. in our web.config file every setting relating to message size was set to the maximum (`int32`). when we run the service it won't accept files bigger than 22 KB.

We did some tracing and we get 1 warning and 1 error. first off we get a warning stating:

> Description   The configuration system has detected a duplicate key in a
>   different configuration scope and is overriding with the more recent
>   value.

And an error stating that the maximum message size was exceded [64 KB].

Problem is we get this error on files from 23 KB and up despite the fact that we did put the absolute maximum size in the web.config. the warning says the config file is being overwritten but by what? ive looked everywhere for the past 3 days for a solution and nothing i have found works.

Anyone have any idea what might be wrong? what could possibly be overwriting the `web.config` file? and if for whatever reason it is overwritten by default values why wont it even accept messages bigger than 22 KB.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT: FOUND THE PROBLEM**

Ok for those still having similar problems i'm going to put here what i found solved them for us.

The usual message size configurations ofcourse

```
<binding maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">            
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32"
         maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
          maxArrayLength="2147483647"
          maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
          maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        </binding>
```

and another setting which i found by accident in a sample code which fixed the problem (ran tests on files up to 64MB in size without any further problems)

```
<system.webServer>
<serverRuntime uploadReadAheadSize="2147483647"  />
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483647" />
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
</system.webServer>
```

Apparently the `requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength` was set very low by default and it was overriding all the other settings presumably because it's a security setting.

The `serverRuntime uploadReadAheadSize` can affect the maximum size but not in the direct sense. I am not very good at explaining so you would probably be better off reading the official documentation on it.

Answer (score 0):

The only point of updation or change in Web.config file is when you **update the service reference**.
Or 
If you have written code to update the the Web.config file contents.

Answer (score 0):

First, read Jon Galloway's post about [web.config inheritance](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/01/17/10-things-asp-net-developers-should-know-about-web-config-inheritance-and-overrides.aspx).

Second, message size depends on more than the file size. Binary data in an array will be base64 encoded (adding ~30% size). The choise of encoding will also affect the message size. UTF-16 will send 2 bytes for each character, while UTF-8 uses a multi byte schema.

Comment: the encoding is set to UTF-8 and even with a 1000% increase in size the files should still be received. the message size is set to absolute maximum (2 GB) and it is refusing to receive anything higher than 22 KB. looked at the post and haven't found anything that might be wrong with ours. the web.config was done by someone much better at wcf than me.